# SQL Query - I can I sum up the values for the same country

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made this query:

```
SELECT        Projects.proj_contract_value, customers.cust_name, customers.cust_country
FROM            customers INNER JOIN
                Projects ON customers.id = Projects.id
                Where Projects.proj_date >= Convert(datetime, '2013-01-01' )
                Order By cust_country
```

Which returns me exactly what I coded:

```
216000000   OBB                     AUSTRIA
380000000   Eurotunnel              FRANCE
42000000    FAL                     ITALY
66000000    Ferrovie della Calabria ITALY
34200000    Ferrovie del Gargano    ITALY
247300000   Ferrovie del Sud Est    ITALY
85000000    Sistemi Territoriali    ITALY
10239000    Ferrovie Nord           ITALY
33100000    Spoorwegen              NETHERLANDS
184000000   RZhD                    RUSSIAN FEDERATION
119000000   Prasa                   SOUTH AFRICA
273000000   Renfe                   SPAIN
1423000000  Thurbo                  SWITZERLAND
285000000   SBB                     SWITZERLAND
1800000000  TCDD                    TURKEY
```

My final target is to get rid of the customer names and get the values of each country summed up per country so that I can get the total value per country. I am battling to get it out. How can I do that?

Comment: If `proj_date` is a `date` or `datetime` column, you can change `>= Convert(datetime, '2013-01-01')` to simply `>= '20130101'`.

Comment: What does "doesn't like it" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Is the data type not a date-related data type? If not, what is it, and why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The error I got was "impossible to find the stored procedure". That is quite strange in this context. But because I was having the result with the previous query I did not investigated further. After your question I tried again and I had same problem. I cancelled the query, past it back and the error disappeared. So, it is also working. I do not know what was wrong. Thank you and sorry for the comment that I have however removed.

Comment: Perhaps you should invest some (more) time to reading about these things in the docs. I mean, your question really had to do with basic knowledge of grouping/aggregation in SQL – not something one is expected to ask about on a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.cust_country, 
       sum(p.proj_contract_value) as value_sum
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN Projects p ON c.id = p.id
Where p.proj_date >= Convert(datetime, '2013-01-01')
group by c.cust_country
Order By c.cust_country
```

Comment: Just perfectly working and returning what I was looking for. Thanks.